# Getting Mongo Network Error while connecting to mongo atlas uri

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I am using mongo Atlas uri and getting mongo network error . Sometimes it works but sometimes it throws error.

> Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 13.234.241.108:27017

```
Server started on port 5000
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 13.234.241.108:27017
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1137:16) {
  name: 'MongoNetworkError'
}
something wrong with DB
```

mongoDb Uri

```
mongoose
  .connect(
    `mongodb+srv://pratham:<password>@cluster0.gxwve.mongodb.net/twitter-clone?retryWrites=true&w=majority`,
    {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useCreateIndex: true,
      useFindAndModify: false,
      keepAlive: true,
    }
  )
  .then(() => {
    console.log("DB Connected");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
    console.log("something wrong with DB");
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the following two things

1. Make sure MongoDB is running on the specified machine
2. Make sure the bindIP in config is modified to accept connections from other IPs

I think it may be something wrong with the MongoDB server. This error occurs due to a low internet connection. Just wait a bit and the program worked as usual.
Also, use Async and wait when every your make request with MongoDB server

```
const connectDB = async () => {
    const conn = await mongoose.connect(`mongodb+srv://pratham:<password>
        @cluster0.gxwve.mongodb.net/twitter-clone?retryWrites=true&w=majority`, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useCreateIndex: true,
        useFindAndModify: false,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    }).then(() => {
        console.log("DB Connected");
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        console.log("something wrong with DB");
    });
};

// use as a function        
connectDB();
```

Comment: Also I thinks that this error occurs due to network issue . Because sometimes it works fine but sometime throws error . so How to resolve that ?

Comment: did you try async and wait

Comment: where should I use async and await ?

Comment: code works at this time . Hope it will work nicely in the future also . Thank you